# How to conditionally call procedure in prepared statement?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

I am trying and failing to do something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'Cleared' = ? THEN call alarm_clear_check(?, ?) ELSE call alarm_create(?,?,?,?) END
```

Unfortunately I cannot merge these into one procedure, so I need to call them like this in a single statement.

So far it looks like there is no way but I was wondering if somehow I can call a procedure conditionally like this?

Comment: This looks like it ought to work. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: No, you can't use call like this.  Could you create a third procedure that handles this logic?

Comment: `CALL` is an SQL statement, not an expression that you can use inside another expression.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create another proc due to restrictions and this does not work (I tried)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using PL/pgSQL like so:

```
do $$
begin
if 'Cleared' = ? 
   call alarm_clear_check(?, ?) 
else 
   call alarm_create(?,?,?,?)
end if   
end $$
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work as a jdbc prepared statement though and I cant create a separate proc

Comment: hmmm...  then you have to handle it in your back end code